# New React App, 404 Not Found error with service-worker

Tags: reactjs, express

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

`/app/index.html?_sw-precache=b2fb08479efcd43b49512c6f06f4bb17`

This is the error I'm getting when trying to deploy my new react app. I'm using Express to serve the static files, as well as the service worker from create-react-app, but I can't seem to figure out why this particular request fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the service worker that comes included in `create-react-app`? or something custom you've written?

Comment: good point. i wrote this too quickly, shouldve mentioned that. yes, it's the create-react-app service-worker.